# Injecting Multiple Angular Modules/Controllers onto Same Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I am trying to inject a new angular controller into a drop down menu, which is in a view primarily populated with another module and controller. So far it does not work, and I do not know why, necessarily. I am not using routing or anything like that,
purely calling the controllers and modules in the html.I am not too sure where else to look. Currently, I am injecting ng-app into a div wrapper, with different locations. However, this does not allow the angular controllers and modules to work in unison Here is snippet of my code:

```
<div ng-show="showme=='4'">
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
      <div class="datagrid">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Checks/Offers Received </th>
              <th> Disbursement </th>
              <th> Client Ins Settled Amount </th>
              <th> Case Fee Percentage</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<body>
<div ng-app="offer">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="OfferCtrl">
      <div class="datagrid">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <td>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Offers</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <li ng-repeat="offer in offers | filter:{clientid:clientId}">
                    <input type="text" value="{{offer.offeramnt}}" />
                    <a href="#">Offer 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Offer 3</a>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<body>
<div ng-app="check">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="CheckCtrl">
      <div class="datagrid">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <td>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Checks</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <li ng-repeat="check in checks | filter:{clientid:clientId}">
                    <input type="text" value="{{check.checkamount}}" />
                    <a href="#">Check 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Check 3</a>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
      <div class="datagrid">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="string" value=" {{client.checksreceived}}" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" value="{{client.clientinssettlesamnt}}" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="number" value="{{client.casefeepercent}}" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Adverse Settle Amount </th>
              <th> Case cost </th>
              <th> Line Item Fees</th>
              <th> Loan Information </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:'id' | filter:{id:clientId} | limitTo: 1 track by $index" ">
       <td>
        <input type="numer" value=" {{client.advsettleamnt}}"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="number "  value="{{client.Casecost}} "/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="number "  value="{{client.lineitemfees}} "/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text "  value="{{client.bdf}} "/>
       </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   <button type="submit " ng-click="updateClient() "><strong>Update</strong></button>
 <a class="btn btn-primary " href="/intakeoffer/{{clientId}} ">
 <strong>Add Offer</strong>
 </a>
 <a class="btn btn-primary " href="/intakecheck/{{clientId}} ">
 <strong>Add check</strong>
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Please provide more information and your controller for your view would be nice too.

Comment: no, but when I view it data will not show on the behalf of the offer and check sections

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) you can read:

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.

So bootstrapping like you've planned is not working. Also multiple ng-app's with same name won't work and the `ng-show` (with-out controller and with-out app - not in your markup) is not working because nesting `ng-app` is not supported.

Manual bootstrapping syntax is like:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

I wouldn't structure my app like this. Just create one app module where you're adding your other modules as dependencies.

e.g. `angular.module('app', ['order'])`

I would also recommend to read some tutorials for getting started with AngularJs. For example the [PhoneCat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: The two app module instances are of the same module, but I took a break in the middle to inject two other modules, "offer" and "checks". But, in the app module, can I declare the other modules as dependencies and still call them onto the same HTML document?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/multiplecontrollers/ . I see they only call ng-app once, in the body wrapper. I thought that without specifying what module to use, it wouldn't instantiate multiple controllers with different modules ?

Comment: You can add multiple dependencies to your root app and use the controllers from these modules at html tags like in the multi-controller example. No need to bootstrap the dependent modules.